# I can't get chat search by user to work

Tags: discussion

If I go to the "root access" chat room and in the search I type something, and then I get the advanced search screen

[image]

If I type in searching for: windows,    when said by: barlop

it lists  a bunch of things but not me saying "windows" though there's no doubt i've said the word "windows" in that chat.  But it shows none of my messages.

is it broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is it broken?

No it is not broken.

You need to search by your ChatID (`1256`) and it will fill in your User Name for you:

[image]